# External display for Macbook goes black on certain rotation

Tags: mac, display

I have a Dell external display for my MacBook. I'm trying to get it to rotate 90 degrees so I can code easily on it, but when I set it up like that in Display preferences the screen goes black.

Why is this happening, and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

See this discussion on Apple:

https://discussions.apple.com/thread/6602333

"Try changing the system to use the discrete graphics card instead of the Intel one"

Comment: How do I do that (MBA 2015)?

Comment: https://www.howtogeek.com/288346/how-to-tell-which-graphics-chip-your-macbook-is-using-and-switch-it/